# how to filter data based on the latest date of a date group?

Tags: r, datetime, filter

i know my question is not as clear as it should be so i hope my explanation will make it more comprehensible. I have a data like this:

```
# total_call data
call_id | from_number | retrieved_date
1         1             2020-01-12 12:03:34
2         1             2020-01-12 12:06:34
3         2             2020-01-15 13:02:40
4         2             2020-01-15 13:05:40 
5         1             2020-01-12 13:09:34
```

I want to group the calls by the `from_number` and the  `retrieved_date` variables, which its time must be within 1 hour since the earliest. After 1 hour, it belongs to a new group. Then i want to filter the latest time of each group. This is the result i want:

```
# total_call data
call_id | from_number | retrieved_date
2         1             2020-01-12 12:06:34
4         2             2020-01-15 13:05:40 
5         1             2020-01-12 13:09:34
```

Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert  `retrieved_date` to `POSIXct` format, `arrange` the data and create a new group when the current `retrieved_date` is greater than previous `retrieved_date` by more than an hour and select the row with max `retrieved_date`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(retrieved_date = lubridate::ymd_hms(retrieved_date)) %>%
  arrange(from_number, retrieved_date) %>%
  group_by(from_number) %>%
  group_by(gr = cumsum(difftime(retrieved_date, lag(retrieved_date, 
            default = first(retrieved_date)), units = "hours") > 1),add = TRUE) %>%
   slice(which.max(retrieved_date)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   select(-gr)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  call_id from_number retrieved_date     
#    <int>       <int> <dttm>             
#1       2           1 2020-01-12 12:06:34
#2       5           1 2020-01-12 13:09:34
#3       4           2 2020-01-15 13:05:40
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(call_id = 1:5, from_number = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L), retrieved_date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L), 
.Label = c("2020- 01-12 12:03:34","2020-01-12 12:06:34", "2020-01-12 13:09:34", 
"2020-01-15 13:02:40", "2020-01-15 13:05:40"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```